# Where to find Server Administration in MySQL Workbench Community 6.0?

Tags: stored-procedures, mysql, mysql-workbench

How do I access server administration console in MySql workbench 6.0 community edition? I cant seem to find it in my downloaded version. I guess I need it to backup my database and the stored procedures associated with it.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open a connection to your server (via its tile on the home screen). In the sidebar at the left you have now 2 sections: MANAGEMENT and SCHEMA. Depending on whether you use the combined or separate view each of the section is on its own tab or stacked together:

[image: Stacked or combined view] [image: Separated view]

Either way you directly have now access to e.g. the backup/restore facitlities.

Comment: Great! Was struggling to find this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

#### On Windows (tabs are at the bottom):

[image]